# Can you use a column as one of the data in the months_between function?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to use a column full of data in the months_between(data1, data2) function?

For example, can I create a view with a set of employee's names and ages, where the ages are calculated from their "birth" column?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean something like this ? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/61995/4

Comment: BTW, since 11g there is the *Virtual Column* concept which might meet your requirements http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28279/chapter1.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, generally you can use a column in any function, it's a database! For instance:

```
select a.*, months_between(sysdate, dob)
  from users a
```

As A.B.Cade suggests in the comments using a [virtual column](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#sthref4994). This has the benefits of storing the data in a table, i.e. it can be indexed and statistics can be collected whilst at the same time giving the "always up-to-date" benefits of something calculated on the fly in a view. Unfortunately age is not deterministic, it changes regularly dependent on the current sysdate and so virtual columns can't work.

Creating a view should be fine:

```
create or replace view users_age as
 select u.*, floor(months_between(sysdate, dob)/12) as age
  from users u;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ea51/1)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm much more comfortable using functions etc. in SQL now; gradually getting used to it :)